# C# Issues returning the proper Task<bool> value from and async Task<bool> function

Tags: c#, fivem

I am trying to create a "minigame" or "skill check" system of sorts in FiveM.

I have an export that I wish for external scripts to call and receive a True or False callback depending on if the player passed or failed the skill check.

```
public void RegisterExport(string name, Delegate action) => Exports.Add(name, action);
        
public bool gameStarted = false;
public bool gameWon = false;

public ClientMain()
        {
            RegisterExport("startGame", new Task<bool>(StartGame));
            RegisterNuiCallbackType("finish");
            EventHandlers["__cfx_nui:finish"] += new Action<ExpandoObject, CallbackDelegate>(Finish);

        }
        
        private async Task<bool> StartGame()
        {
            
            gameStarted = true;
            SendNuiMessage(@"{""startGame"":true, ""number"": 4}");
            SetNuiFocus(true, true);

            Debug.WriteLine("Game started");

            while (gameStarted)
            {
                await Delay(100);
            }

            Task<bool> result = new Task<bool>(() => gameWon);
            result.Start();
            return await result;
            //return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => gameWon).Result;
            //return gameWon;

        }
```

The RegisterExport line, specifically the `StartGame` is underlined stating the wrong return type. I have tried swapping out the return to `return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => gameWon).Result;`

It states it is returning a `Task<bool>`, but still StartGame at the top says `Incorrect return type, Task<bool>`

Comment: You declared `RegisterExport` to accept a `Delegate` - but a `Task<bool>` is not a delegate

Comment: Also, if you eventually manage to stuff your async StartGame method into your Exports collection, remember that it is nevertheless an async method returning a Task/Task<T> instance that should be awaited in some way or another. Otherwise, funny things will quite likely happen with your program, and troubleshooting/debugging any weird behavior will be the best fun you will ever have in your life...

Comment: Looks like C# does not support what I wish to do... I will probably resort to switching to Lua... C# can't wait in a non-async function, and I need to wait for the game to end before trying to return the result of the game... In Lua you can wait wherever and whenever... It's unfortunate, as I prefer C# over Lua.

Comment: I believe you want to have `Task` that you can control completion of - hence I believe duplicate I picked is what you are asking. If not - please [edit] the question to clarify what you want that code to do as plain text explanation (possibly part of your comment may be that).